# Select DISTINCT Query Corrupts result in record set

Tags: c++, database, select, distinct

I've used recordset to populate combobox. When I write normal select query the output comes out to be correct but when I write select query with **DISTINCT**  the combobox is populated with weird strings. Could anyone tell me as to what I'm doing wrong.

```
allSqlUsername.Format(_T("SELECT PatientName from PatientDetails;"));
    recsetname.Open(CRecordset::forwardOnly, allSqlUsername, CRecordset::readOnly);
    while (!recsetname.IsEOF())
    {
        recsetname.GetFieldValue(L"PatientName", patientNameC);
        m_autocompletename.AddString(patientNameC);
        recsetname.MoveNext();
    }
```

New select query - `allSqlUsername.Format(_T("SELECT DISTINCT PatientName from PatientDetails;"));`

[image: Dropdown with populated values]

[image: Output with wierd string append]

Comment: ...if/once my edit has been approved modify your question such that the main text plus problem is above your code and images. In that order it helps to better understand your question from the start. Welcome and enjoy SO ;-)

Comment: Hi @ZF007 I've modified the question.

Comment: Well done Pranav! It looks much better now... hope someone appreciates the effort and is able to help you out. (spotted minor: wierd = weird. my review task is done. GL ;-)